# Correct way to provide cache backend in Django

Tags: python, django

I am following [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#s-creating-a-sitemap-index) of Django docs trying to add cache to generated sitemaps. Docs provide following sample code:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import views as sitemaps_views
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('sitemap.xml',
         cache_page(86400)(sitemaps_views.index),
         {'sitemaps': sitemaps, 'sitemap_url_name': 'sitemaps'}),
    path('sitemap-<section>.xml',
         cache_page(86400)(sitemaps_views.sitemap),
         {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='sitemaps'),
]
```

It works as expected and caches result in my default cache (redis).
But since I have really large sitemap, I would the cache to be stored in file cache, not in memory. My django `settings.py` does include required settings:

```
CACHES = {
    # Redis cache
    "default": { ... },
    # File cache
    "file": { ... },
}
```

However when I try to specify correct arguments to `cache_page` decorator:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('sitemap.xml',
         cache_page(86400)(sitemaps_views.index)(cache="file"), # <--- !!!
         {'sitemaps': sitemaps, 'sitemap_url_name': 'sitemaps'}),
]
```

I receive an error:
`TypeError: _wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Which is the correct way of providing cache backend in such case ?

Comment: I don't see `(cache="file")` in the docs why you adding it ?

Comment: @Ahtisham See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache  which includes following sample: `@cache_page(60 * 15, cache="special_cache")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up the function calls. Instead of

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('sitemap.xml',
         cache_page(86400)(sitemaps_views.index)(cache="file"), # <--- !!!
         {'sitemaps': sitemaps, 'sitemap_url_name': 'sitemaps'}),
]
```

it should be

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('sitemap.xml',
         cache_page(86400, cache="file")(sitemaps_views.index), # <--- !!!
         {'sitemaps': sitemaps, 'sitemap_url_name': 'sitemaps'}),
]
```

The argument `cache` needs to be in the `cache_page` call.

Comment: Thank you @jmangold, it worked. (i hate decorator syntax :))